# Links are not working in tabs of WHMCS template

Tags: javascript, templates, whmcs

I'm designing a bootstrap responsive template for WHMCS in local but in **"productdetails"** page I created 3 tabs which onClick, the information appears where the links in first tab work fine but the links in second and third tab are *not* working! (links in all pages work fine, even I have the same tabs in other pages and there links working fine)

Tried to put the links between *div* and even *p* tag, but not worked.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: also tried taget="_blank" but not worked

Comment: does the browser console gives you any error messages when you click tabs?

Comment: but some time it comes: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: I have a file in this location: js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js . when I comment it, all the problem go away but I should use this for other purposes. Any idea?

Comment: Check other functions based on jquery, if WHMCS jquery is loaded they should work. if no, read about jquery noConflict, may be it can fix the issue for you.